# Who is the "son of a bitch" that Dick Best is referring to?

Tags: dialogue, midway-2019

While on board a plane, Dick Best contacted his flying squadron after seeing enemy warships:

> Dick Best: God damn it. **That magnificent son of a bitch** actually found them.
>
> Dick Best: (*on radio*) All right, boys. Bombing Six, we've got the first bastard in line.

Who is Dick Best referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He's clearly referring to McClusky, who in an earlier scene spotted a single carrier, which he speculated was trying to catch up to the rest of the fleet. They decided to follow it and indeed came upon the fleet.